# Meteor + Iron Router unable to scroll up

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have tried using command like scrollTo(0) and packages like okgrow:router-autoscroll. I have read through many pages online. I am completely unable to make it so that when I load a new template via route (Iron Router) it automatically scrolls to the top.

Edit: I have tried all of the following to no avail:

```
$(window).scrollTop()
$('body, html').scrollTop()
$('body').scrollTop()
$(document).scrollTop()
window.scrollTo(x, y)
```

Comment: sucks to be you......now how are we supposed to help you? there's no code,  we need something concrete to give feedback on. Try posting a very minimal code example of what you are trying to do

Comment: Thanks for the respectful reply. 

I included the packages I tried, along with the jquery .scrollTo(). As far as I'm concerned those are methods that should work, and was hoping someone would let me know if there was an ongoing Meteor/Iron Router issue that they are aware of a solution for.

I will edit my post with 'more' codes. Though I would appreciate less disrespect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you with the same issue. I ended up solving this with problem in all browsers with the following code:

```
Template.templateName.onRendered(function(){
    $('.wrapper-header')[0].scrollIntoView();
});
```

This should work in all browsers as it did for me, and remove the necessity for flowrouter and Iron Router autoscroll addons.

Hope this helps!